# How to hide Root node in TreeView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building nodes dynamically from a DB table. When I run the code the node root node also appears which wont go away. I have tried everything. Looked up on the internet but haven't find a specific solution for this problem.

My ProductCategory table looks like this

[image]

Here's the code in .cs file

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GetTreeViewItems();
        }
    }

    private void GetTreeViewItems()
    {

        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ProductCategories where ParentId in (0,1,2)", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        ds.Relations.Add("ChildRows", ds.Tables[0].Columns["ProductCategoryId"],
            ds.Tables[0].Columns["ParentId"]);



        foreach (DataRow level1DataRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(level1DataRow["ParentId"].ToString()))
            {
                TreeNode parentTreeNode = new TreeNode();
                parentTreeNode.Text = level1DataRow["ProductCategoryName"].ToString();
                parentTreeNode.Value = level1DataRow["ProductCategoryId"].ToString();
                parentTreeNode.NavigateUrl = "?catid=" + level1DataRow["ProductCategoryId"].ToString();

                int i = (int)level1DataRow["ProductCategoryId"];
                GetChildRows(level1DataRow, parentTreeNode);

                    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(parentTreeNode);
            }
        }
    }

    private void GetChildRows(DataRow dataRow, TreeNode treeNode)
    {
        DataRow[] childRows = dataRow.GetChildRows("ChildRows");
        foreach (DataRow row in childRows)
        {
            TreeNode childTreeNode = new TreeNode();
            childTreeNode.Text = row["ProductCategoryName"].ToString();
            childTreeNode.Value = row["ProductCategoryId"].ToString();
            childTreeNode.NavigateUrl = "?catid=" + row["ProductCategoryId"].ToString();


            treeNode.ChildNodes.Add(childTreeNode);

            if (row.GetChildRows("ChildRows").Length > 0)
            {
                GetChildRows(row, childTreeNode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. I you want a node to be invisible, but it's children to show, then the only way is not to add the root node, and add the children as root nodes.

Either that, or write your own TreeView control.

Comment: Ok I figured that out too that it's not possible. What if I want to disable the root link. I mean, if I make it unclickable. Is there a way?

Comment: Depending on the control, you might be able to set Enabled = False. Exactly what effect this will have (both on the Node and on the Children) will depend on which control you are using.

Comment: It does sound like the best thing is not to add the root of your hierarchy, but to add its children as TreeView root nodes (and their children as child nodes). TreeViews generally aren't limited to one root node.